# Sync: Error Logged In Console (Help menu > Toggle Developer Tools)

Tags: synchronization, visual-studio-code, sync-settings

I want to sync my settings to VSCode using Sync extension. I have installed the extension, logged in to my github and selected the gist. Now when I try to *Sync: Download Settings* it throws the following error. Can someone help to sync my settings ?

> Sync: Error Logged In Console (Help menu > Toggle Developer Tools).

Comment: The message is more than clear. Open VSCode's Developer Tools and see the actual error message and learn what's wrong there.

Comment: [Extension Host] Error: Error: Error: Extension 'vincentkos.snippet-creator' not found.

Comment: When it points to an extension with ownership issues, I doubt if you should continue using that, https://github.com/nikitaKunevich/vscode-snippet-creator/issues/18

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `extensionsGallery` section of the `product.json` file in your VSCodium installation to use the VS Code Marketplace as shown below. However, note that it is not clear whether this is legal.

```
"extensionsGallery": {
    "serviceUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery",
    "itemUrl": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items"
}
```

If you're a debian user try `locate product.json`
In my case I found it in `/usr/share/codium/resources/app/product.json`
Then edit this file

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your gists
2. Click on cloudsettings
3. Click on Edit
4. Find your stucked extension name from extensions.json and **REMOVE** those data

as like ---

```js
{
  "metadata": {
    "id": "42e46dd6-3444-4b25-be5c-ddd5ecf2baa7",
    "publisherId": "ms-vscode.brackets-pack",
    "publisherDisplayName": "ms-vscode"
  },
  "name": "brackets-pack",
  "publisher": "ms-vscode",
  "version": "0.1.1"
},
```

5. Update
6. Download again